# Issue with Okta in Aspnet.Core Web API InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, okta

Currently I have an angular 6 front-end that is successfully sending an Okta access token to my Asp.net Core Web API 2.1 that is hosted on IIS 7.5.

However I get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

In IIS I have turned off Windows Authentication and enabled Anonymous. I'm not sure if I have to do anything extra because sometimes the Chrome browser to do an options (http verb) first.

In my startup.cs I have done this:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions()
            {
                ClientId = _configuration.GetOktaClientID(), //static method to get OktaClientID from Config file
                OktaDomain = _configuration.GetOktaDomain(),//static method to get Okta Domain from Config file
                Audience = "api://default"

            });

        services.AddMvcCore(opts =>
        {
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("API_READ", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new BasicAuthorizationFilter("API_READ")));
             })
            .AddFormatterMappings()
            .AddCors()
            .AddDataAnnotations() // Optional if no validation using attributes
            .AddApiExplorer()     // Not Optional
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            })
            .AddJsonFormatters(o =>
            {
                o.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                o.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            });
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .WithExposedHeaders("X-InlineCount")
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

I have a controller to test things with:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var principal = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;


        return Ok(principal);

    }
```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with [samples-js-angular](https://github.com/okta/samples-js-angular/tree/master/okta-hosted-login) and [samples-aspnetcore](https://github.com/okta/samples-aspnetcore/tree/master/resource-server), it works correctly with your configuration.

Comment: I actually fixed the issue in my debugger by switching the order in my configure method to app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();  However, it still gives me problems when I release to my IIS Server.